# How do you extract only the number from the result of subtracting two dates?

Tags: r, date

When I subtract two dates in R, I get the result seen below.

[image: Result of subtracting two dates in R]

How would you extract only the number from this result without getting all the associative text?
Is there a way to do it without having to write a parsing function?

Answer (score 2):

We can convert to numeric wiwth `as.numeric/as.double`

```
as.numeric(diffObj)
```

based on the

```
methods(class = 'difftime')
```

According to `?difftime`

> The as.double method returns the numeric value expressed in the specified units.  The units of a "difftime" object can be extracted by the units function, which also has a replacement form

---

A reproducible example would be

```
out <- Sys.Date() - (Sys.Date() - 2)
out
#Time difference of 2 days
as.numeric(out)
#[1] 2

units(out)
#[1] "days"
```